# How can I fix Vim's line breaking behavior for long lines in Python?

Tags: python, vim, pep8

So here's my problems. Let's say I have a Python file and I'm typing a really long line, like the last one here:

```
class SomeClass(object):
  def some_method(self):
    some_variable = SomeOtherClass.some_other_method(some_parameter=some_value)
```

When I type this in Vim, this happens:

```
class SomeClass(object):
  def some_method(self):
    some_variable =
    SomeOtherClass.some_other_method(some_parameter=some_value)
```

That's not just bad style, it breaks PEP8. What I'd like to happen is:

```
class SomeClass(object):
  def some_method(self):
    some_variable = SomeOtherClass.some_other_method(
        some_parameter=some_value)
```

Which is in keeping with [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (For the purposes of this discussion, I'm only interested in the line breaking behavior, not the indentation behavior.)

**Edit:** `breakat` only works in conjunction with `linebreak` to govern how lines are displayed. It does not (apparently) work in conjunction with `textwidth` to determine where hard line breaks are inserted. So my idea below will not work...

Surprisingly, I have found nothing out there indicating others share this problem, which leads me to think I'm doing something wrong. Nevertheless, my idea was to add the `(` character to the `breakat` setting (along with `[` and `{` while I was at it).

I've tried this; here's the output of `:set breakat`:

```
breakat= ^I!@*-+;:,./?([{
```

However, it's to no avail. No matter what I do, Vim insists on breaking after the "=" above. I have this same problem with long function names as well, where it'll break right after `def`.

Here are the complete contents of my .vimrc:

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set columns=80
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
set smarttab
set smartindent
set textwidth=80
set wrap
set breakat=\ ^I!@*-+;:,./?\(\[\{
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```

(I have no plugins etc. installed for the purpose of trying to figure this out.)

Does anyone have any idea how I can get Vim to obey my breakat setting, or any other thoughts about the best way to deal with this behavior?

Comment: added note about pythonTidy to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't setting linebreak. Without it, vim ignores the breakat variable. See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks) for details, and lots of vim goodness. Also note that you need to set nolist as it breaks linebreak.

Another blog post dealing with word wrapping [here](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/03/vim-textwidth/). This one notes that some filetypes do not auto include the format options "t" flag. Without it, auto wrapping does not occur.

I think the simplest thing to do would be to add in a mapping to run `:%! pythonTidy`. [pythonTidy](http://www.lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/) is a script, in python, to take python code on stdIn and output a pretty version to stdOut. With that mapping, it will allow you to run it on your current file, and replace the entire contents with the reformatted version. Add an autocommand to run this whenever you exit insert mode in python files, and you should be set.

Comment: Hm. Tried it with `set linebreak` and `set nolist`. That doesn't work for me. In fact, I even tried removing the space char from breakat. This did not change the behavior. When I am in the midst of typing a long line, Vim just breaks a new line at the space no matter what I do...

Comment: Okay, well I see the problem. `linebreak` and `breakat` only govern the way lines are displayed, whereas `textwidth` inserts actual hard line breaks. This is the behavior I want. It seems, however, that textwidth is "dumb" and only adds line breaks at whitespace. So I guess I need a way to modify textwidths line break insertion behavior?

Comment: Since he mentioned PEP8 i think he wants hard linebreaks, i.e. no lines longer than 80 chars. However, I'd rather use 100-char lines - 80 is pretty short, especially if you have some hardcoded strings - and nowadays almost nobody is really limited to 80 chars terminal width

Comment: I am not *limited* to 79 characters; but I use vertical splits to see several source files at once (or the same file at many separate locations), and when there are breaks at that column, I find it much easier to read.  If I *really* need to work on a lot of separate files, I can reduce the font size and get three splits!  100 columns just won't ever fit nicely with vertical splits.

Comment: @jsdalton As far as I am aware, the only way to change this behavior of textwidth is to get the vim source code and add in a new feature.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun Thanks for your answer and comments; I believe sadly that you are right. I'll likely `set textwidth=0` for Python files and use something like `colorcolumn` to visually flag long lines instead, unless someone comes along with an alternative solution.

Comment: @jsdalton Not a problem. You may want to check into the pythonTidy bit I added. Adding in an autocommand to run it is something vim can do easily. Grab the script, run it on your code, and see if you like it. If you need help with setting up the autocommands, you can open another question.